# CSS selector is not updating after click on element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is my markup:

```
<p>This is <span class="rounded">some</span> text which <span class="rounded">shows</span> what I <span class="rounded">want</span> to do.</p>
```

I have the following CSS:

```
span.rounded:not(.clicked):nth-child(1) {
            background: red;
        }
```

So, this turns the background of first `rounded` element to `red`.

Now, if i click on the word `some`, it applies a class `clicked` to the wrapping `span` tag. The HTML now looks like this:

```
<p>This is <span class="rounded clicked">some</span> text which <span class="rounded">shows</span> what I <span class="rounded">want</span> to do.</p>
```

At this point, I expect to word shows to have a red background because it seems to satisfy the selector:

```
span.rounded:not(.clicked):nth-child(1) {
            background: red;
        }
```

However, no other tag ever becomes `red`. What am I doing wrong?

How can I make the next tag red after the current one has been clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using JS to add a class to the span on click?  Why not just make your rule this?
`.clicked{
    background: red;
}`.
`nth child(1)` is looking for a child element of span, it doesn't have a child.

Comment: @MonsterBasket, `:nth-child()` looks for the first child of the *parent* element. In this example, it targets the first child of `<p>`, which is the first `<span>`.

Comment: I don't personally believe this is possible, as the pseudo-selector applies before the logic gets set. Therefor, `:not(.clicked):nth-child(1)` never has a valid target. You're setting the class in JavaScript though -- why not just make use of `element.style` to update the colour at the same time?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Sorry, you're right, I also mis-read the requirement.  How about `span.clicked + .rounded:not(.clicked)`?

Comment: @MonsterBasket yes, I am using JS to add the class on click. Technically, I am using jQuery instead of pure JS but that shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: @RealNoob nah, it's your CSS.  My last comment should get the next sibling of any span that is clicked and turn it red if it's not clicked.  If that doesn't work / not what you want maybe make a jsfiddle and I'll have a look.

Comment: @MonsterBasket Thanks that worked as expected. I thought the adjacent sibling selector works only if the elements are side by side with not even text nodes between them. Could you please explain why did the selector that I wrote not work?

Comment: Thanks to @ObsidianAge for pointing this out, but it's looking for the 1st span child of the p, and THEN checking if it's clicked or not.  It's not looking for the 1st unclicked child.

Comment: Thanks @MonsterBasket. Is there any place where I can read about the order in which selectors are applied? I thought it goes from left to right.

Comment: Like @ObsidianAge said, pseudo-selectors (e.g. `:nth-child`) are considered __before__ logic ones (line `:not`), so this query ultimately doesn't affect any element.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tk0orL3g/ like this?

Comment: I'm actually doubting that what I just said is true now actually.  Can't find any good documentation, but I *think* it just kinda stacks the pseudo selectors, rather than doing them sequentially, so order doesn't matter.  Do NOT quote me on that lol

Comment: @Praveen yes, something similar to that but I only want to turn backgroudn red if the next sibling doesn't have the clicked class. The selector suggested by MonsterBasket works well for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise the comments, and someone please correct me if I'm wrong on this first point, but this:

```
span.rounded:not(.clicked):nth-child(1) {
            background: red;
        }
```

Doesn't work because it will always find the 1st child of the `<p>` parent that is a span with class rounded, and if it is not clicked, it will apply the rule.

This solution does work:

```
span.clicked + .rounded:not(.clicked)
```

This will look for a span that is clicked, find the next span with class rounded, and apply the rule only if it's not clicked.